# Can't load html from local file in PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

Using Selenium and PhantomJS, I can load a file from a server running on localhost like this:

```
_driver.Url = "http://localhost:52873/Home/Template";
```

Where `_driver` is an instance of `RemoteWebDriver` that connects to an instance of PhantomJS running on a port (launched with `--webdriver=9134`). And I can call a Javascript function defined in that HTML file like so:

```
var val = _driver.ExecuteScript("myFunction()");
```

However, I would like to load it from the local file system rather than through the local webserver, so I tried something like this:

```
_driver.Url = "file://c:/path/to/Home/template.html";
```

An I get no errors, but when I try to execute a script that is defined in the `html` file, it does not work. It throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message `Can't find variable: myFunction`. However, if I set `_driver` to an instance of `ChromeDriver` instead, I can see the page load and everything works as expected, both using `http` and `file` protocols.

I get no additional information from the PhantomJS console window, so I don't really know what the problem is. I suspect for some reason PhantomJS just isn't loading the page. Any ideas?

Also, is there any way using the .NET binding for selenium to get access to the console log? I added a `console.log("connected")` to my html file to run as soon as the page loads, but it doesn't get echoed to the phantomJS console either when run from `file` or from `http`, so that's not much help.

Comment: Does the html include references to remote resources? If yes, you probably need to set `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` when running the PhantomJS server.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: It includes relative paths to other files that are also local files. Something like `<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`. I tried `--local-to-remote-url-access` just on the off-chance, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: As a debugging step I would try using [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to identify if there is some permission issue with PhantomJS accessing those files.

Comment: Arrrgh: never mind, the problem was that I needed `file:///` not `file://`. Chrome auto inserted the extra `/` while Phantom did not. I notice it my comparing the actually URL in the address bar when running it on Chrome and noticed the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an extra / in the path URI.

```
_driver.Url = "file:///c:/path/to/Home/template.html";
```